# Turtlebot gazebo

Tags: simulation, turtlebot, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can i install Turtlebot_simulator on my Fuerte Ubuntu 12.04 ??
Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45193/turtlebot-gazebo/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.

Assuming that you've properly followed [the instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu), you can type:

`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot-simulator`

or you can choose to install it from source from the location included on the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_simulator).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3